# Obter todos os Itens Steam

Tags: php, json

Bom, eu tenho o seguinte código que faz com que obtenha os itens de um inventário de um determinado jogador. Contudo ele só me mostra 1 tipo de cada item, ou seja se o jogador tiver 5 caixas do mesmo tipo, ele só me exibe 1 caixa.

Como faço para mostrar todas as caixas?

Código:

```html
$steamid = $_COOKIE["steamid"];






$destUrl = 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' . $steamid . '/inventory/json/730/2/';

$data = file_get_contents($destUrl, false);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$data1= array_keys($data['rgDescriptions']);
$data2= $data['rgDescriptions'];
for($i = 0; $i < count($data1); ++$i) {

    echo '<br> ID: '. $data1[$i];
    echo '<br> Name: '. $data2[$data1[$i]]['name'];
    echo '<br> Market_Hash_Name: '. $data2[$data1[$i]]['market_hash_name'];
    echo '<br> Market_Name: '. $data2[$data1[$i]]['market_name'];
    echo '<br>';


}
```

Obrigado

Comment: Você poderia me mostrar em qual doc você conseguiu este link para verificação do inventário? Não consigo executar o link de jeito nenhum!

Comment: Está aqui o link: http://steamcommunity.com/id/CSGOSort/inventory/json/730/2/

Comment: Talvez só mostre uma caixa, pq talvez tenha um campo `quantidade` que marque cinco, como no seu exemplo. Coloca o print_r de `$data`

Comment: Existe um campo `amount`, que te diz quantos items ele tem daquele tipo